# Continuing Work on the Spring BlazeDS integration?

Tags: spring, apache-flex, blazeds, spring-flex

I am part of the `Apache Flex` team and currently taking care of the `BlazeDS` development. We are currently working on a great number of improvements in `BlazeDS` and I noticed the Flex Integration sub-project got re-located to the Attic. I would like to step up and continue work on this module. Especially change it to using `Apache Flex` `BlazeDS` instead of `Adobe BlazeD`S.

What do I have to do? Who do I need to contact? Is there any interest in me doing this?

Comment: The [Attic site](http://attic.apache.org/) has instructions for restarting a project. You should ask their mailing list if necessary, this is off-topic for SO.